# Unable to execute spark job from Robot Framework by using SSH Library

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

I am trying to execute a spark job from robot framework.

```
Execute Command    su hdfs -c 'spark-submit --driver-java-options "-Xss4m" --master yarn --queue..etc /home/automation/actual'
```

Its not getting executed from robot framework. Please help me if anyone knows this.

Comment: Get any errors ?

Comment: Hi @rasjani. I am getting below output in console

Comment: 20220714 20:01:12.032 :  INFO : Command exited with return code 1.
20220714 20:01:12.032 :  INFO : ${STDOUT3} = 
20220714 20:01:12.033 :  INFO :